# Metric (other than RMSE, MSE, etc.) to select the best model to better detect peaks in weather forecasting

Tags: python, regression, model-evaluations, metric

I have created multiple regression models and wanted to choose the best one. One common metric would be RMSE, as you know.

When I looked at the results, the second model (RMSE = 0.15) was better able to detect some of the peaks than the first one (RMSE = 0.1). For example, look at the two results:

Best model (RMSE = 0.1):
[image]

Here is the second model's result(RMSE = 0.15):
[image]
The **model** which is able to **detect all the peaks, as much as possible** (**although its RMSE is not the least among all of the models**), is more preferable to a model which has less RMSE but is not able to detect peaks.
I searched through the web but didn't find what I was looking for.

Can anyone suggest to me a code to evaluate the results of the models, based on their ability to detect peaks better?

Suppose the results are simply 2 arrays:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
predicted_1 = np.random.rand(10, 1)
predicted_2 = np.random.rand(10, 1)
original = np.random.rand(10, 1)
```

Comment: Are you interested in all of the peaks, or only the _largest_ peaks? What about troughs - what should the metric indicate then?

Comment: The model which predicts all of the peaks is more preferable. My model is a weather forecasting one. Hence, it's ability to detect peaks is of high importance for me. It should be able to detect all of the peaks. Large and small ones. The more it detects the peaks, the less the error should be.

Comment: Hw about estimating correlation? See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157791/find-phase-difference-between-two-inharmonic-waves. Perhaps this can be used along with your RMSE somehow.

Comment: @TwinPenguins Thanks.Using R-squared along with RMSE seems interesting. as discussed here: 

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38631/rmse-vs-coefficient-of-determination.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in my work before and used weighted RMSE and assigned higher weights to the peaks.

Some ideas I took from here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230517/weighted-root-mean-square-error

Comment: This seems a suitable approach to my problem. However, I'm not sure what type of weight function to use. The first weight function that came to my mind is to divide the current **Y_original** by sum of all **Y_original**s. Could you please explain your weight function?

Comment: Yes, you could try  Y_original by the sum of all Y_originals, but you need to be aware that these weights favor peaks with bigger Y value. You could try to make a numerical derivative of the signal and give bigger weights to the points with a derivative close to zero. You could do smoothing first if tiny peaks do not matter. The derivative has a known effect of increasing noise. It depends.
 In my previous work, I used threshold, that assigns weights to the values bigger than the threshold, but the signal was completely different.

Comment: Thanks. I got the main idea.